# Default value in time_field in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I'm new to Rails and in my view i've a form like

```
 <label id="starttime">From</label>                   
 <%= time_field :time, "FromTime" %>                   
 <label id="endtime">To</label>                    
 <%= time_field :time, "ToTime" %>
```

How to set a default value to the time input field.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a `form_for` on the page, and usually the form object is passed as `f`, and that your database fields are `starttime` and `endtime`. In that cases your code, with a default would look like:

```
<%= f.label :starttime %>
<%= f.time_field :starttime, value: Time.now %>
<%= f.label :endtime %>
<%= f.time_field :endtime, value: Time.now %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a default value to a time_field input, in your case you have to do:

```
<%= f.time_field :starttime, "From time", value: Time.now %>
<%= f.time_field :endtime, "To time", value: Time.now %>
```

Or if you don't want to specify the current time, try:

```
<%= f.time_field :starttime, "From time", value: Time.parse('8:00') %>
<%= f.time_field :endtime, "To time", value: Time.parse('10:00') %>
```

Also, you can use other options like `:min`, `:max` and `:step`. For more info you can check this [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/time_field)